# General method for Galois Field multiplication

Tags: galois-theory

I'm wondering if there is any general method I can use to generate reference values other than using these lookup tables mentioned in the following link.

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/develop-set-tables-similar-table-53-textbook-gf-4-modulo-x2-x-1--determine-multiplicative--q16622093

Comment: Whenever I wrote a computer programs to do stuff with finite fields (characteristic two only in my case) I always started out by generating look-up-tables of discrete logarithms (and the inverse table). You can use those to do both addition and multiplication [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). You use discrete logarithms just like the usual logs, but must remember that they are defined modulo $q-1$.